# Is there a difference between Static Classes vs Import prefixes?

Tags: dart

I have a file in the app folder named `constants.dart`.

An example of a constant is

`const String name = "Daniel";`

I want to be able to use the const variables from the file by typing `Constant.name`.

What's the difference between making a class named `Constant` and putting public static variables or by importing my constants file with `as constant;`.

Is there a third option?

What if it's a utils file and I have methods with no side effects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The officially recommended style is to use top-level constants, [not have a class containing them](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members).

That allows users to import them with any prefix (not just `Constant`) or even without a prefix, if they really want to.

Using a class as container is *arbitrary*. You can use a `class`, a `mixin` or an `extension` declaration to declare constants. All three introduce a static namespace on top of what they otherwise do, and if the static namespace is all you care about, you can use any of them.

To be honest, if all I really want is a namespace, I'd probably do:

```dart
// Namespace containing utility functions!
extension MyConstants on Never {
  static int foo() => 42;
  static const int = 10;
}
```

and not use a class. That way, it won't introduce a *type* that is never used for anything anyway.

Or really, I'd follow the style guide and do top-level declarations instead.

Comment: I care about the namespace because I'm concerned about shadowing variables and stuff like that. The extension idea is very clever